# React material-ui dynamically adding Expansion Panel on button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to dynamically add an Expansion Panel using React Material UI. It is added, but I am unable to expand it (i.e `isExpanded` is true even when the panel is not expanded). I am on Material UI version 4.4.1 and React.js version is 16.9.0. Can anyone help me figure out why it doesn't work as expected?

```
const TransportFlow = () => {
        const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState('');
        const [points, setPoints] = React.useState([]);
        const handleChange = panel => (evt, isExpanded) => {
            setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
        };

        const addPoint = () => {
            const arr = [];
            const pointPanel = (
                <ExpansionPanel key='p1' expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')}>
                    <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} id="panel1bh-header" aria-controls="panel1bh-content">
                        Hello
                    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                    <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                        <Typography>Some more text</Typography>
                    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>
            );
            arr.push(pointPanel);
            setPoints([...arr]);
        }

        return (
            <div className="flow">
                {points.map((point) => point)}
                <button className="add-waypoint" onClick={() => addPoint()}>Add</button>
            </div>
        ); }
```

Link to Code Sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-thunder-5rbro?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you're rendering the points, you are not providing them any props (like expanded). 
So, when you click on the expansion panel, you change the state and trigger render on TransportFlow. 
point is a child of TransportFlow , but it doesn't render because 'point' props didn't change (because you don't send to it expanded prop, it doesn't care when the expanded state has changed). 
The solution is change the structure a little, so you can provide 'point' with props:

```
const TransportFlow = () => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState("");
  const [points, setPoints] = React.useState([]);
  const handleChange = panel => (evt, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };
  const addPoint = () => {
    const arr = [];

    arr.push('dummy'); //just to notify there's something in the array
    setPoints([...arr]);
  };

 const PointPanel = (props) => (
    <ExpansionPanel
      key="p1"
      expanded={props.expanded === "panel1"}
      onChange={props.handleChange("panel1")}
    >
      <ExpansionPanelSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        id="panel1bh-header"
        aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
      >
        Hello
      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
      <ExpansionPanelDetails>
        <Typography>Some more text</Typography>
      </ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanel>
  );

  return (
    <div className="flow">
      {points.map(point => <PointPanel  expanded={expanded} handleChange={handleChange}/>)}
      <button className="add-waypoint" onClick={() => addPoint()}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see I used addPoint only to notify there's something in the array (if you'll want more than one expansion panel- you will need to change the structure a bit)
I also extracted PointPanel to a component - so you can provide props to it.

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-shadow-eizt3?fontsize=14) example.